# UI View doesn't seem to use translucent Navigation Bar

Tags: ios7, uitableview

I'm updating an App to support iOS7. I have a Tab control with a number of tabs - several table views and one UI view. The strange thing is that IF the Navigation bar in the top is translucent, it has a different appearences depending on whether the tab control shows a table view or the UI view. The navigation bar seems to always be opaque when the UI view is selected.

Unchecking "Extend Edges - [ ] Under top bar" in the table views also make the navigation bar the same color for all views.

So the question boils down to that the navigation bar for the UI view doesn't seem to be translucent?

Answer (score 0):

Set the navigationBar to be translucent in your viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```